# Expire cache based on saved value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

In my app there is a financial overview page with quite a lot of queries. This page  is refreshed once a month after executing a background job, so I added caching:

```
@iterated_hours = Rails.cache.fetch("productivity_data", expires_in: 24.hours) do
  FinancialsIterator.new.create_productivity_iterations(@company)
end
```

The cache must expire when the background job finishes, so I created a model `CacheExpiration`:

```
class CacheExpiration < ApplicationRecord
  validates :cache_key, :expires_in, presence: true
end
```

So in the background job a record is created:

```
CacheExpiration.create(cache_key: "productivity_data", expires_in: DateTime.now)
```

And the `Rails.cache.fetch` is updated to:

```
  expires_in = get_cache_key_expiration("productivity_data")
  @iterated_hours = Rails.cache.fetch("productivity_data", expires_in: expires_in) do
    FinancialsIterator.new.create_productivity_iterations(@company)
  end

  private def get_cache_key_expiration(cache_key)
    cache_expiration = CacheExpiration.find_by_cache_key(cache_key)
    if cache_expiration.present?
      cache_expiration.expires_in
    else
      24.hours
    end
  end
```

So now the expiration is set to a `DateTime`, is this correct or should it be a number of seconds? Is this the correct approach to make sure the cache is expired only once when the background job finishes?

Comment: What does that background job do? Especially, does it update any records in the DB? If so, it would be safer and more versatile (but would require one DB roundtrip) to rely on the update_at field of the record updated.

Comment: The background job created a huge number of records + the cache expiration record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly setting an `expires_in` value is very limiting and error prone IMO. You will not be able to change the value once a cache value has been created (well you can clear the cache manually) and if ever you want to change the background job to run more/less often, you also have to remember to update the `expires_in` value. Additionally, the time when the background job is finished might be different from the time the first request to the view is made. As a worst case, the request is made a minute before the background job updates the information for the view. Your users will have to wait a whole day to get current information.

A more flexible approach is to rely on `updated_at` or in their absence `created_at` fields of ActiveRecord models.

For that, you can either rely on the `CacheExpiration` model you already created (it might already have the appropriate fields) or use the last of the "huge number of records" you create. Simply order them and take the last `SomeArModel.order(created_at: :desc).first`

The benefit of this approach is that whenever the AR model you create is updated/created, you cache is busted and a new one will be created. There is no longer a coupling between the time a user called the end point and the time the background job ran. In case a record is created by any means other than the background job, it will also simply be handled.

ActiveRecord models are first class citizens when it comes to caching. You can simply pass them in as cache keys. Your code would then change to:

```
Rails.cache.fetch(CacheExpiration.find_by_cache_key("productivity_data")) do
  FinancialsIterator.new.create_productivity_iterations(@company)
end
```

But if at all possible, try to find an alternative model so you no longer have to maintain `CacheExpiration`.

Rails also has a [guide on that topic](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html)

Comment: I didn't know about passing an AR model as the full cache key, thanks!

Comment: Glad the information is useful. From personal experience, I'd also opt for including the application version into the cache key. Otherwise altered views might not show up after deployment. E.g. [OpenProject does that](https://github.com/opf/openproject/blob/dev/lib/open_project/cache/cache_key.rb)